# twbsPagination totalPage value always changing?

Tags: javascript, jsp, pagination

```
 $('#pagination').twbsPagination({
                totalPages: "5",
                visiblePages: "5",
                onPageClick: function (event, page) {
}
```

I have a list that can be filtered by 10, 100 and 1000. If the database has 12 document and the user uses the 10 filter, the totalPages would essentially be 2: 10 on the first page, and 2 documents on the second page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how do you retrieve information. In the case of AJAX-call you could do this way, after receving result:

```
  var $pagination = $('#pagination');
  var totalValue = 25; //for example
  var toShow = 20; //show 20 items
  var numOfPage = Math.ceil(totalValue / toShow);
  if (numOfPage > 1) {
      var totalPages = numOfPage;
      var currentPage = $pagination.twbsPagination('getCurrentPage');
      $pagination.twbsPagination('destroy');
      $pagination.twbsPagination($.extend({}, defaultOpts, {
                startPage: currentPage,
                totalPages: totalPages
      }));
   } else {
      $pagination.twbsPagination('destroy'); //don't show pagination 
                                             //if all item on the 1st page
   }
```

**UPDATE** on that `onPageClick: function (event, page) {}` event you should assign next ajax call and in success put provided code. Something like this.

```
  onPageClick: function (event, page) {
      loadNextValues(page); //function to retrieve information.
      //most probably you need this assignment -> page = page -/+ 1
      //I don't remember exactly 
  }
```

This pagination is lazy-loading. At least provided algorithm.